# Yeshua Sar Ha-Panim

Tags: history, prayer-book

"*Yeshua Sar Ha-Panim*" is mentioned in some machzorim in the following prayer between the shofar blasts on Rosh Hashanah:

> יהי רצון מלפניך שתקיעת תשר"ת שאנחנו תוקעין תהא מרוקמת ביריעה על ידי הממונה (טרטיא"ל) כשם שקבלת על ידי אליהו ז"ל וישוע שר הפנים ושר מט"ט ותמלא עלינו ברחמים. ברוך אתה בעל הרחמים.

Does anyone know who this is referring to? I know from an [article by Dr. Yehuda Liebes](http://pluto.huji.ac.il/~liebes/sarhapanim.doc) this is a reference to Yehoshua bin Nun. Are there further references/sources to this?

Comment: Who else could it be?  What other Yeshua was a leader who was defined by who he faced? (i.e. the moon to Moshe's sun)

Comment: @avi, indeed, that's the reason I want sources evidencing it.

Comment: @RenatoGrun what do the acronyms in the quote mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Artscroll Rosh Hashanah machzor translates the phrase as "Yeshua [the Kohen Gadol] minister of the Inner Chamber".

But the sefer יצחק ירנן [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_21258_263.pdf) he discusses this name at length, and says that the name is not found in any ספרי קבלה, nor is it one of the seventy names of the שר הפנים. The closest name which is in the list is ישעיהו and from this the author concludes that a long time ago one of the censors changed the name in accordance with his beliefs, and could not be changed because of fear of the censor, and subsequent printings continued to print this error.

He concludes that one should not say the name at all rather than change it to a name it might have been, e.g. ישעיהו, since we cannot know for sure what the original name was.

---

[Here](http://www.bhol.co.il/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=991870&whichpage=2&forum_id=1364) is another discussion which I will quote in case the link becomes broken:

> עוד בענין "צלמים בהיכל" מה שזיפו הנוצרים. ‏
>
> הביא בספר "עלבונה של תורה" הנ"ל מ"שפ"ן הסופר", וז"ל, זיפו בתפלות שבין התקיעות והכניסו בין המלאכים הממונים על התקיעות את "ישוע" שר הפנים, והוא "ישוע" הנוצרי מלאך חדש שנתמנה על ידי אוהביו לשר הפנים. כן נדפס בסדורים ומחזורים כמעט בכל הדפוסים זה מאות בשנים. ‏
>
> ומעשה שהיה שאחד מסוחרי הספרים בתימן קנה מדפוס ראם ספרים רבים ומתוכם גם סדור תפלה אחד לדעת נוסחתנו השונה הרבה מנוסחת התימנים. ויהי כי ראה הרב (החכם) שלהם את שם המלאך הנ"ל וישתומם ויחרד ויצעק אהה ! המדפסים ראם הציבו צלם בהיכל קודשנו ! נבלה נוראה עשו לנו להטעות לבבנו אל אל זר בשעה קדושה ורוממה כזו ! בשעה שכל לבבנו רוחנו ונשמתינו קדושות להפנות לבבנו ודעתו לאל זר ילוד אשה ? ‏
>   המדפיסים המסיתים האלה אשר הציבו את הצלם בהיכל תפלותינו הלא מינים הם וספריהם הנם ספרי מינים, ואסורים לכל ישראל, ויאמר להכריז איסור גמור על כל ספרי דפוסם כדין "ספר שכתבו מין ישראל", ויהי בשמעי את דבריו החריפים ותאחזני פלצות וחרדה גדולה, כל כל הוני ורכושי תקועים בספרי ראם, ואם יגזור עליהם להחרימם ואצא נקי מכל רכושי ואשאר אביון ! והרב הוא גדול מאד ליהודים, גאון בתורה ובקבלה וחסיד מפורסם, וכל היוצא מפיו ישמעו כל היהודים בתימן ואהיה בצרה גדולה ! ובצרתי לי קראתי לה' ויענני, כי נקרא אלינו פתאום חכם צדיק אחד מחכמי ירושלים לימי ראש השנה, וישמע את הדבר הזה ויעל בראשון לימי הזכרון אל הבימה וישבע בשם אלקי ישראל שכבר נדפסה לפנים בדפוסי אירופה קודם דפוס ראם הנוסחה הזאת ולא מיחו בהם חכמים, ודפוס ראם נקי. ויבטל הרב את האיסור אשר אסר מעל ספרי ראם, ואברכה את ה' אשר חלץ נפשי מצרה. ‏
>
> אך צוני לשאול להמדפסים ראם אולי ידעו מתי ואיך יצא הזיוף הזה בקרב ישראל, אבל לא ידענו להשיב לו, אפס כי למען אז בערנו הצלם מספרינו. עכ"ל. ‏
>
> ובמחזור "בית דין" (ליוורנו, תרי"ח) שהוצ"ל ר' אברהם חמוי (מחכמי אר"ץ) בעמוד קכ"ו כתב וז"ל, בתוכי ישתמומם לבי בראותי בסידור נהורא השלם ודרך חיים לאשכנזים וסידור קול יעקב ובשאר מחזורים ביהי רצון שבין התקיעות נמצצא שם בין שמות המלאכים משרתי עליון שם ישו"ע שר הפנים בלתי נודע המיסד תפלה הלזו איזה איש אשר נזרקה בו רוח מינות. ‏
>
> ולמטה אכניס צילום שאר דבריו בטענתו שזה זיוף מחסידי שבתי צבי, ובסוף הספר המחזור הוסיף קונטרס שלם של שבעים השמות הידועים ממאלך הפנים והשם ויוש"ע הנ"ל אינו שם. ‏

Comment: @user4523 or anybody, please add a translation and/or summary.

Answer (score 4):

Saar Ha-Panim is Metatron, my source is Rabbi Yoel D. Bakst from Colorado. The Gaon of Vilna mentions Metatron in Kol Hator.

edit:

http://www.yedidnefesh.com/kaballah/kol-hator/1.htm
I think the phrase translated as "minister of the interior" is from the Hebrew phrase "Saar Ha-Panim". Kol Hator states that Metatron is Yosef.

edit2:

Here's a quote from Rabbi Bakst, who quotes Rav Hillel of Shklov in Kol Hator

The Twin Messiahs are the two pulsating currents of divine  energy  —  din  (or  gevurah)/constriction  and hesed/expansion  —  manifesting  within  the  historical space-time  of  each  and  every  generation.  Although  each messianic  current  is  a  distinct  force  field  of  energy  that appears  to  repulse  the  other,  it  is  the  very  tension  they generate  that, when  channeled  and  directed,  becomes  the most  powerful  force  for  personal,  national,  and  planetary change that has ever existed. Their paradoxical natures are continually present  in  every  thought  and  action,  and  they are waiting to be channeled.

R. Hillel explains

- A  fundamental  rule  is  that  during  the  performance  of every mitzvah  and  every  tefilah,  one  should  contemplate the unification [of the Trein M’shechin] and bind oneself to the  "Two  Armies  of  God" —  [these  being  the  two  divine names]  E-lohim  Tzevaot  (God  of  Armies)  and  Y-HVH Tzevaot  (Lord  of  Armies),  din  (constriction)  and  hesed (expansion). One must [then] calculate the line of balance between their two numerical values — 499½ from the left side and 499½ from the right side.*

Each  of  the  two  messianic  polarities  has  within itself a number of sub-currents  that  interact  together  in a cacophony of pulsating social, political, and religious events

to  generate  the  ever-rising  threshold  of Formula 999.  In a divinely  orchestrated  fashion  they  all  act  according  to specific laws contained within the 156 Aspects of Mashiach ben  Yoseph.  It  is  they  who make  up  the members  of  the Two  Armies  of God.  In Kol HaTor's Messianic Conspiracy, they are the Appointed Agents of God.

R. Hillel writes

- The thrice-woven cord of "Signs," "Designated Times," and "Appointed  Agents"  appears  simultaneously  in  a  three-pronged  campaign. The "agents"  react  to  the  "signs"  and thus accelerate the arrival of the "designated times." This is alluded to in the verse, "The blossoms have appeared in the land; the time of singing has arrived, and kol hator — the call of the turtledove — is heard in the land" (Song of Songs 2:12).  "The blossoms have  appeared" —  these are the  signs;  "the  time  of  singing has  arrived" —  these  are the designated times; "the call of the turtledove  is heard" — these are the appointed agents.*

These  agents  are  vehicles  for  the  different  aspects, or  mini-personalities  which,  like  pieces  in  a  puzzle,  only when  they  are  fit  together  constitute  the  totality  of Mashiach ben Yoseph.43 They  include,  for example, names like  Ephraim  ben  Yoseph,  Shirya  ben  Dan,44  Eliyahu HaNavi  (Elijah  the  Prophet),  the  archangels  Gabriel, Sandalfon,  and  **Metatron**,  Neriya,  Menachem,  Ezra  and Nehemiah,  **Yehoshua  ben  Nun**,  Sasson  and  Simcha. (Sasson and Simcha are explained in Chapter 4, Metatron.)

There  is,  however,  one  all  encompassing Mashiach ben  Yoseph  archetype  that  we  must  mention  briefly. Initially  it  appears  to  confuse  an  already  overly  complex pantheon  of messianic  archetypes,  yet  it  is  precisely  here where all the various aspects of Mashiach ben Yoseph come together. This is the climatic evolution of Formula 999  into the Great Thousand. This is the cosmic image of Moses our Teacher together with the Two Messiahs.

- My words:
  So I guess I'm saying that Metatron and Yehoshua Ben Nun are both agents of the Messianic Redemption, and that some of those agents have aspects of the others in them. Hanoch became Metatron, if I'm not mistaken. Maybe Yehoshua Saar Ha-Panim refers to the Metatronic aspect of Yehoshua Ben Nun.

Comment: Or [Suriel](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=51&format=text), but what does this have to do with the question?

Comment: Sorry if it's not what you're looking for, but all I know about the phrase Saar Ha-Panim is that it is Metatron. My knowledge of Torah is beginner-level. How would the question be explained to a beginner? I'm not Jewish I'm a ben Noah.

Comment: How is this not an answer to the question?

Comment: @avi so there could be more than one. The question wasn't "Who's a Sar Panim", it's "who is Yehoshua a Sar Panim"?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I added what may be a better answer.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, actually I would like to know if there was another sources of tradition pointing out to Yehoshua bin Nun. In this sense, user4651's answer was a very thoughtful insight.

Comment: question, the link http://www.yedidnefesh.com/kaballah/kol-hator/1.htm is broken, but is this it, too: http://archive.li/ExKoB

Answer (score 1):

This is possibly an allusion to none other than Jesus! (accordingly this was inserted by Christians and must obviously be omitted).

This is stated by the [Minhat Elazar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Elazar_Spira) (1:75) citing his father [R. Tsvi Hirsch Spira](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A6%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%A9_%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%90)

> "ישוע" שהוא כמו שם שכינו המסיתים להידוע ר"ל ובשגיאה נשתרבב טעות כזה ה' יצילנו
>
> "Yeshua" which is a name that those who lead Jews astray called the known one (i.e. Jesus), heaven fore-fend, and by mistake such a mistake came about, may God save us!

R. Ovadiyah Yosef quotes this and others who oppose the mention for related reasons in his Yabia Omer (vol. 1 OH 36:18) including R. Yosef Stern in his Zekher Yehossef responsa ([4: 210](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=772&st=&pgnum=97&hilite=)):

> וחזי הוית בשו"ת מנחת אלעזר ח"א (סי' עה)... שאין לומר היהי רצון בין התקיעות...ואכן אף המנחת אלעזר סיים שם בשם הגאון מר אביו (הדרכי תשובה) ז"ל, למנוע לומר היה"ר...כי יש חשש תערובות בכוונות ובשמות בנוסח היהי רצון, וביחוד מ"ש ישוע שר הפנים, שלא מצאנו מקור לזה, והוא כשם שכינו המסיתים להידוע (ישו הנוצרי), ובשגיאה נשתרבבה כאן טעות כזאת וכו'. ע"ש... וכעת נזדמן לידי שו"ת זכר יהוסף, וראיתי אליו (בסי' ר"י) שג"כ כתב לערער על הזכרת ישוע שר הפנים בנוסח היהי רצון, (וכמ"ש המנח"א הנ"ל)
>
> The Minhat Elazar concluded in the name of his father (author of Darkhei Teshuva) that one should refrain from saying the prayer...since there is concern about the wrong names and intentions in it, particularly that which it mentions "Yeshua Sar HaPanim" for which we have no source for, and it is like the name that they termed the known one (Jesus of Nazareth)...And the Shut Zekher Yehossef also writes against the mention of Yeshua Sar HaPanim for the same reason.

However, while R. Stern opposes saying it, and emphasises the dubious nature of this character, and its absence from any classicla Jewish literature, I don't see him say explicitly that it refers to Jesus.

Answer (score 1):

The text of this Yehi Ratzon is a corruption of the proper names of these three angels which are invoked at the time of the blowing of the shofar on Rosh HaShanah.

One of the earliest and most authoritative sources that have we about this is from Rabbi Avraham ben Yitzchok of Rimon in [Sefer Brit Menucha, 4b](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31194&st=&pgnum=7), beginning at the bottom of the first column with the words מן זה מקבל שמוע״אל הגדול כו׳. There are three angels which are referred to as *Sar HaPanim*.

They are Shemui'el (שמוע״אל), Metatron (מטטרו״ן) and Yehaviel (יהו״אל). It is these three angels which are invoked in our prayers according to the Prophets. This is alluded to in Isaiah 43:7 which says:

> כֹּ֚ל הַנִּקְרָ֣א בִשְׁמִ֔י וְלִכְבוֹדִ֖י בְּרָאתִ֑יו יְצַרְתִּ֖יו אַף־עֲשִׂיתִֽיו׃
>
> All who are linked to My name, Whom I have created, Formed, and made for My glory.

The word ב**שמי** is a *Roshei Teivot* for (**ש**) Shemuiel, (**מ**) Metatron, (**י**) Yehaviel. They are also the Heavenly agents assigned over Shmuel HaNavi, Moshe Rabbeinu and Eliyahu HaNavi.

Answer (score 0):

I learned from Rabbi Moshe Aberbach, alav Hashalom, that Yesh Sar HaPanim was inserted to avoid mahzor censorship by anti-semetic Christian authorities who would think the Jews were tolerating an aspect of Christianity.

Answer (score 0):

Likkutei Sichos 29 Hosafot
(Note: there are some minor typos due to cutting and pasting from Hebrewbooks.Please c.f the original))

אין ענטפער אויף אייערע בריף און פראגען:
פראגע א): אין יהי רצון וואס מ׳זאגט צווישען די תקיעות לויט אייניגע נוסחאות
שטייט: ״וישוע שר הפנים״. מעז האט אייר געזאגט, אז דאס האט מען אריינגעגגבט דעם
נאמען פון אותו האיש.
ענטפער: וועגען דארוף איז שדן פיל געשריבען געווארען(טפר מנחת אלעזר -
געדרוקט אין מונקאטש תרס״ב - חלק א, סימן ע״ה, און חלק ב׳ צום טוף. פפר קצה
המטה - קליינווארדיין תרפ״ג. ספר עלבונה של תורה - ברלין תרפ״ט. זשורנאל נרות
שבת - ירושלים, ערב ר״ה תש״ו).
מעז איז געקומעז צום בעשלוס, אז עם דארף שטיין ״וישעיה - אדער וישעיהו -
שר הפנים״ וואס דאס איז איינע פון מלאך מטטרון׳ס נעמען. אויסגעקליבן דעם נאמען
ווייל ער באטרעפט 400 , אזוי פיל ווי ״אליהו הנביא זכור לטוב״ און אויך קר״ק(רמז
אויף תק׳יעה תר׳ועה תק׳יעה). און אזוי האט מען אויך געפונען געדרוקט אין אלטע
מחזורים וספרים. עס איז ווארשיינלין־ אז מיסיאנערען האבען אריינגעגנבט און משנה
געווען רעם נאמען אויף ״וישוע״. באמערקונג: דער בעל התניא ווי אויר דער ווילנער
גאון און נאד גדולי ישראל פםקענעז אז מ׳זאל רעם יהי רצון בכלל ניט זאגען. און אזוי
איז אונזער מ נ ה ג . . .
(ממכתב כ־ו תשרי. היתש־י)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the original perhaps? Also, adding a translation or summary would help immensely. Without at least a summary, this is more of a comment than an answer. See http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/75/759 and http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2187/759